# DAX % of a Measure Above a Certain Threshold

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a DAX measure, that works perfectly, called `CntViewedByUser_YOY`.
If the user is exempt for some reason (asked to be exempt), the value takes N/A, otherwise, it will have a number.

I want to create a DAX measure that counts the total number of records where `CntViewedByUser_YOY` is not equal to N/A and use this as a denominator in a DIVIDE function later on.

For the numerator, I want the value to take a 1 if the value is equal to or higher than 70%, otherwise, 0, unless it's an N/A value, in those cases, I want the count to be ignored.

Example data:

```
CntViewedByUser_YOY
0.00
0.25
0.70
0.85
N/A
```

Numerator = 2
Denominator = 4

Result = 0.50

This is what I tried to use to get the denominator, but then I got an error message.

```
VAR Count_YOY_Adj = 
    IF ([CntViewedbyUser_YOY] <> "N/A" 
    , COUNT(HighlightsMeasures[CntViewedbyUser_YOY])
    ,BLANK()
    )
```

The error message I got is:

```
"Column 'CntViewedbyUser_YOY' in table 'table_a' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression.
```

Comment: It would be good with some actual sample data on how these tables look, and what the expected result is. It's difficult to give you a suggestion on how to solve this using DAX without clear data examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create this below measures-

```
Numerator = 
COUNTROWS(    
    FILTER(
        ALL('Table'),
        [CntViewedByUser_YOY] >= 0.70
    )
)
```

As you have 'N/A' as string value, you can filter liek - **[CntViewedByUser_YOY] <> "N/A"**

**But,** null is preferred in number type column.

```
Denominator = 
COUNTROWS(    
    FILTER(
        ALL('Table'),
        NOT ISBLANK([CntViewedByUser_YOY])
    )
)
```

```
Result = [Numerator]*1.00/[Denominator]
```

Final output-

[image]